# How to implement an effect in iOS that the specified widget appears only when pull it up?

Tags: ios5

I noticed when open the built-in "Messages" app you won't see the search box widget by default. Only when you pull the view up you could see it. It's an interesting effect exactly. Well, I really want to implement a similar effect but what should I start from ?

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! seems found the answer. 
I viewed this post and had a try, and it works.
Cheers!

[Showing the searchbar only when user pull down the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615747/showing-the-searchbar-only-when-user-pull-down-the-table)